# I need to replace an old Basler AC Transformer. I can't find a replacement. How do I determine what to replace it with?

Tags: transformer, ac

It came out of Payne Central AC PA10JA042000ADAA.  I tried emailing Basler - no response.  Any help would be appreciated.  I don't want to replace the whole AC unit for a bad part.  Some numbers from the part.  Thank you.

[image: Basler Transformer]

```
BE-9016-IEF76
50-60 CY.
PRI. 230 V.
DNP 02-0159
SEC. 24 7 ??? Not clear
Class 2 SIG.  UL
```

Comment: "Central AC" = "Air Conditioner"? If that's the case then that transformer is nothing special - is just a 230v (or 240v) to 24v transformer. If you post some dimensions then probably someone here could give a rough estimate of it's VA rating. Sourcing a replacement should be simple.

Comment: I would take a SWAG and say a 40 VA 24V transformer would replace it.

Comment: How do you know it needs replacement?

Answer (score 5):

I will take a SWAG and say a 40 VA 24V transformer would replace it. They are readily available and not expensive. You can try one and see what current your system requires. A clamp meter would work good for this. If it does not overload the transformer you are finished, if it overloads it get a bigger one.

Comment: But first make sure the circuit on the secondary does not draw too much current.